# LibreOffice Impress animations: how to strikethrough on click

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-impress

I'm making a presentation for school, and I wanted to make an animation where some texts get's a strike-through.

Basically ***from this:***

[image]

***To this:***

[image]

I've already looked in the animations and found `Change Font Style` however, it didn't have strikethrough in there.
Google didn't help me either, so I hope somebody here can :)

Cheers

Comment: I don't see a way to achieve this directly. You could fake it by having a second copy of the text on top, struck through, but invisible until animated to appear. That would be fiddly though and make editing awkward.

Comment: Yes, I see, I've already stuck with that for now... they should really build this in :p

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to Insert
2. Choose the Shapes category
3. Choose the line object
4. Draw a line through the text you wish to strike out
5. Animate that line